# Rounding a VAT commission in PHP

Tags: php, math

I want to achieve following: putting a commission with VAT on top but rounding the commission so commission + VAT have a round number. In PHP.

Lets say we have this:

```
50 Euro original Price
12 % + 4 Euro comission = 10 Euro
19 % VAT on the commission only(!)
61,19 total price
```

But what I want to have is

```
61 Euro Total price
```

How do I calculate it, that the commission itself decreases and both, commission and VAT make a round (no decimals) number?

```
$base = 50.00;
$comission = $base * 0.12 + 4.00;
$vat = $comission * 0.19;
$total = $base + $comission + $vat;
```

Thats what I got. Hope you can tell me the clue!

Cheers

Comment: if you just want to round down the total, use `$roundedTotal = floor($total);` see more about `floor` here http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php

Comment: @AlexAndrei but then the VAT changes or not?